# PHP Language level missing latest (version 7.3 is the highest)

Tags: phpstorm

I'm trying to setup Xdebug and while doing that I'm trying to ensure that all PHP-versions and setup of that is exactly right.

I've matched the PHP-version on the server (7.4), by installing and linking the right PHP-version using Brew (I'm on a Mac).

So in a terminal, if I write `php --version` I get: version: 7.4.14:

[image: PHP version on a Mac]

---

I've set the CLI-interpreter in PhpStorm to point to that same PHP-executable:

[image: PHP executable in PhpStorm]

---

But in spite of this, I can only set PHP version 7.3 to be the highest language level:

[image: PHP Language level missing in PhpStorm]

---

### Solution attempts:

All these things have been found in random cracks and articles. None of them worked.

1. Invalidated Cached and restarted PhpStorm ( File >> Invalidate Cache and restart ).
2. Uncheck 'Synchronize IDE Settings with composer.json' in Settings >> Languages & Frameworks >> PHP >> Composer. I had to first insert a path to remove it. But it didn't do anything anyway.
3. Tried to see if there was any upgrades to the "PHP Latest"-plugin, but I couldn't see any pending updates (v. 0.4).

---

### Overarching question

How do I get the latest version in the PHP Language Level field (to also get better code hints)?

Comment: What is your PhpStorm version?

Comment: My version was this: `2018.2.3 - Build #PS-182.4323.68 built September 13, 2018`. I hadn't tried updating PhpStorm. I could see that there is a newer version available (2018.2.7) - this was when I went to PhpStorm >> Check for Updates. But searching online I could see that there is a version 2020.3 available.  After updating to version 2020.3 I can now choose later versions. Thanks, @LazyOne . If you write your comment as an answer, then I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My version was this: 2018.2.3 - Build #PS-182.4323.68 built September 13, 2018

You need to upgrade your IDE. Latest stable version is 2020.3.1.

- Partial PHP 7.4 support is present since [PhpStorm 2019.2 version](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/2019-2/).
- Proper PHP 7.4 support was added in [PhpStorm 2019.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/2019-3/).
- Initial/partial PHP 8 support was added in [PhpStorm 2020.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/2020-2/).
- [Current 2020.3 version](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/2020-3/) has more complete PHP 8 support.

Comment: might help some: I was just "checking for updates" from within PHP Storm, but then found i needed to  Upgrade from the Jetbrains Toolbox I originally used to install the program.